# How to removing an old fragment bundle cache permanently?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, fragmentstatepageradapter

Even when I return POSITION_NONE, while using FragmentStatePagerAdapter, I can see that it removes my fragment and creates the new instance. But the new instance receives a savedInstanceState Bundle with the state of an old fragment. How can I completely destroy the fragment so Bundle is null when created again?

Please see this is my first question on SOF and maybe I am not following rules to ask questions, But I'm trying to brief my question as much as possible. Will ask for more guidance and will put code if asked for.

My Code here: 
MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
public static ArrayList<Integer> page_indexes = new ArrayList<>();


FragmentTransaction mCurTransaction = null;
FragmentManager mFragmentManager ;
private List<Fragment> mFragments ;
private Fragment dummyFragment;
//public static int CURRENT_ORDER_NO = 1;

public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mFragmentManager=fm;
    page_indexes.add(1);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fr =  new FragmentAddOrder();
    mFragments = mFragmentManager.getFragments();
    for(int i=0;i<mFragments.size();i++){

    }
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("position", position);
    fr.setArguments(args);
    return fr;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return page_indexes.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return "ORDER #" + page_indexes.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

public void deletePage(int position)
{
    if(page_indexes.size()>0) {
        page_indexes.remove(position);
        //mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        mFragments = mFragmentManager.getFragments();

        //FragmentTransaction trans = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        //trans.remove(mFragments.get(position));
        //trans.commit();

    }
}
}
```

HomeTabActivity.java

```
public class HomeTabActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
/**
 * The current order number that helps iterate the present order number among various tabs made
 */
private int CURRENT_ORDER_NO = 1;

/**
 * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
 * and next wizard steps.
 */
public ViewPager mPager;

/**
 * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
 */
MyAdapter mAdapter;


TabLayout tabLayout;
TextView tvTotalOrders;
private Boolean isFabOpen = false;
private FloatingActionButton fabMenu, fabPrint, fabDelete, fabAddCustomer;
private Animation fab_open, fab_close, rotate_forward, rotate_backward;
// public PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
// private ArrayList<Integer> page_indexes;
// int orderNumber = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_tab);
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    // mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mPager);
    tvTotalOrders = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalOrders);
    fab_close = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fab_close);
    fab_open = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fab_open);
    rotate_backward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_backward);
    rotate_forward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_forward);
    tvTotalOrders.setText("Orders Running: " + MyAdapter.page_indexes.size());
    fabMenu = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabMenu);
    fabPrint = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabPrint);
    fabDelete = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabDelete);
    fabAddCustomer = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabAddCustomer);
    fabMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
    fabPrint.setOnClickListener(this);
    fabDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
    fabAddCustomer.setOnClickListener(this);
    //page_indexes = new ArrayList<>();
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
    /*mAdapter.deletePage(mPager.getCurrentItem());*/
}

/**
 * Author Vibhu Jain
 * Date Created : 11 July 2017
 * Date Last Modified : 11 July 2017
 * Desc : This Function is responsible to inflate options menu in the ActionBar/ToolBar of the activity.
 * <p>
 * Last Modification:
 */
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
/**
 * Author Vibhu Jain
 * Date Created : 10 July 2017
 * Date Last Modified : 11 July 2017
 * Desc : This Function is responsible for onOptions Items actions performed
 * when a certain action is selected on ActionBar OptionsMenu.
 * <p>
 * Last Modification: Added setText statement for No. of Orders running
 */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.addTab) {
        CURRENT_ORDER_NO += 1;
        MyAdapter.page_indexes.add(CURRENT_ORDER_NO);
        tvTotalOrders.setText("Orders Running: " + MyAdapter.page_indexes.size());
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // do something here
    }        
    if (id == R.id.printAll) {
        Intent webviewIntent = new Intent(this, WebviewDemoActivity.class);
        startActivity(webviewIntent);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
/**
 * Author Vibhu Jain
 * Date Created : 11 July 2017
 * Date Last Modified : 13 July 2017
 * Desc : This Function is responsible for onClick actions performed
 * while clicking of Floating Action Buttons Group.
 * <p>
 * Last Modification: Added fabAddCustomer in the group with necessary onClick action as asked by Sunit Kumar.
 * Added call to webview to generate print for each order
 */
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.fabMenu:
            animateFAB();
            break;
        case R.id.fabPrint:
            Intent webviewIntent = new Intent(this, WebviewDemoActivity.class);
            webviewIntent.putExtra("OrderNo",""+(mPager.getCurrentItem()+1));                //Toast.makeText(this,""+mPager.getCurrentItem()+1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(webviewIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.fabDelete:
//mPager.removeViewAt(mPager.getCurrentItem());
            //mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem()-1);
            mAdapter.deletePage(mPager.getCurrentItem());
            //mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            tvTotalOrders.setText("Orders Running: " + MyAdapter.page_indexes.size());
            break;
        case R.id.fabAddCustomer:
            Intent intentDialogActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityDialogCustomerAdd.class);
            startActivity(intentDialogActivity);
    }
  }
}
```

FragmentAddOrder.java

```
public class FragmentAddOrder extends Fragment {
ArrayList<String> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> quantity = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Double> price = new ArrayList<>();

/**
 * Declaring an ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView
 */
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
AutoCompleteTextView textProductView;
TextView txtEmpty;
EditText itemQuantity;
String selectedItem = "";
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager;
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 6;
int positionNum = 1;
int positionNumSIS;
int intItemQuantity = 0;
double doubleProductPrice = 0;
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    positionNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("position") : 1;
}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRetainInstance(false);
    return inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    txtEmpty =  view.findViewById(R.id.txtEmpty);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //probably orientation change
        positionNumSIS = (int) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("positionNum");
        if (positionNumSIS == positionNum) {
            itemsList = (ArrayList<String>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("itemsList");
            quantity = (ArrayList<Integer>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("quantityList");
            price = (ArrayList<Double>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("priceList");
            if (itemsList.size() >= 1) {
                txtEmpty.setText("Total Items: " + itemsList.size());
            }
        }

    }     
 //Rest of the work is my Fragment's Work to do with      
}  
/**
 * Author Vibhu Jain
 * Date Created : 11 July 2017
 * Date Last Modified : 12 July 2017
 * Desc : This Function is responsible for saving up the Fragment's List items so that they persist when a new tab is added
 * or an existing tab is deleted.
 * <p>
 * Last Modification: Added positionNum for testing purposes
 */
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("itemsList", (Serializable) itemsList);
    outState.putSerializable("quantityList", (Serializable) quantity);
    outState.putSerializable("priceList", (Serializable) price);
    outState.putSerializable("positionNum", positionNum);
}
//This function is not so usable for now, can be ignored
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    if (this.isRemoving()) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().remove(this).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

}

Basically, what I am trying to do is to add some tabs in viewpager to get some orders in it.  While adding more tabs, while the ongoing data in the other tabs are retained.
If a certain tab is needed to be deleted, it should be deleted along with its bundle state and so that the other fragments(in tabs) does not get affected and their data is retained.

But now, when I try to delete my tab, it just replaces tab to the tab position forward and moves the existing fragment's data in that next tab.

Hope this clarifies my problem, if any other code/help required, I'll be prompt to reply.

Comment: please add your code

Comment: @MichaelMeyer I have added the code.